# porto theme pagination on woocommerce not working

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, themes, shortcode, pagination, twitter-bootstrap

here i use code shortcode of woo commerce and whenever i reload page pagination showed up then hide

i used this code

[products limit="12" columns="5" paginate="true" visibility="featured" ]

and when i check with inspect tool

[image]

the css have

element.style {
opacity: 1;
display: none;
}

this code but when i uncheck diplay pagination showed up and i found a this line in content product archive

do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' );
?>

```
<div class="shop-loop-after clearfix" style="none"> </div>

<?php
```

nothing happen if i change style setting\

plz someone help me out

i m using default option not ajax pagination style

Answer (score 0):

ok i add these code in additional css

.shop-loop-after {
display: block !important;
}
.shop-loop-before {
display: flex !important;
}

pagination showed up but when i click to change page , pagination and deafualt sorting not working and also not changing into list style or grid style